# How could I check time that android application takes until the user can use it

Tags: android

I'm a system engineer on android platform.
I suddenly need any way that is used to measure(or estimate) app launch time.
I mean 'app launch time' is how long the app takes to be ready for use(i.g. user
can use that app, in other words, the app can respond to any events(touch, drag and drop or etc)).

Is there any way? please advice to me.

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: I think that depends on the hardware of the device, like processor ram etc. As far as I know, you can't get this information directly, but have a look at android application lifecycle. You may find some thing close to what your'e looking for.

Comment: is this for your app or just any app installed on the device?

Comment: @Nickey, people are taking time of their day to help you, the least you can do is say that that is not the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In your ´Application´ subclass in ´onCreate()´ get time via ´System.currentTimeMillis()´ and compare it with the time you get after the last action you have to perform before your user can use your app. Success obviously depends on wether your app initializes the same way every time.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a value for reports, you can launch the app, then:

```
adb logcat -b events -d | grep am_activity_launch_time
```

The entry is generated by the Activity Manager -- see `windowsDrawn` in [ActivityRecord.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-mr2-release/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityRecord.java) (line 767).

This is not an officially supported mechanism.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use LogCat to measure the time.
You can only start to measure time when your app is running but you can search the LogCat associated with the launch(it is better if you click on your app icon and search for it un the logcat entry);
[image: main activity launch log]
Then just override `onResume` on your main activity and put:
`Log.d("time_start","time launch");`
[image: your log]
Then just calculate it! In this case: 960-560

Cheers

Comment: Hi, Dyna. I just want to know how long it takes to launch any android application.